# checkedListBox event - get selected item/object properties

Tags: winforms, events, object, checkedlistbox

I'm populating a checklistbox with an object the processes a path into components. How do I get a specific property from the object associated with the selected index? I'm currently using the SelectedIndexChanged event I've tried SelectedItem, SelectedValue, SelectedIndex. I can get the property type, but not the value with checkedListBox1.SelectedValue.GetType().GetProperty("fullPath"). Thanks.

```
            Class1 c1;
            List<object> files = new List<object>();

            foreach(var value in filteredFiles1)
            {
                c1 = new Class1(value);
                checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "fileName";
                files.Add(c1);                    
            }

            checkedListBox1.DataSource = files;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to cast the `CheckedListBox` `SelectedItem` to an instance of your class, and then access any properties within scope. Here is an example:

```
    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 c = (Class1)checkedListBox1.SelectedItem;
        MessageBox.Show(c.fileName);
        MessageBox.Show(c.fullPath);
    }
```

I advise to do some additional checking to make sure the object is not null (i.e. in case the `SelectedIndex` became -1).